# dc.BeginDialogAsync: "Value cannot be null.\nParameter name: options"

Tags: c#, azure-bot-service

Everytime I run `await dc.BeginDialogAsync("sign-in");` I get this exception which makes no sense since the rest of the parameters are optional. It makes me super confused. Here is my code:

```
public FlexoBot(ConversationState conversationState)
{
    this.dialogState = conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("dialog-state");
    this.dialogs = new DialogSet(this.dialogState);

    // Make oauth card available to use for all handlers
    this.dialogs.Add(new OAuthPrompt("oauth", new OAuthPromptSettings() { ConnectionName = "flexo-auth" }));
    dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("sign-in", new WaterfallStep[] {
        PromptSignIn,
        GreetUser,
    }));
}


protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var dc = await this.dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext);
    foreach (var member in membersAdded)
    {
        if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
        {
            await dc.BeginDialogAsync("sign-in");
            // Throws: System.ArgumentNullException has been thrown "Value cannot be null.\nParameter name: options"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. It's because I was calling `return step.PromptAsync("oauth", null);` in one of my waterfall steps. I changed it to:

```
return step.PromptAsync("oauth", new PromptOptions { });
```

And it works now.